# Having the navigation bar follow a segue custom transition

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to have a new controller come from the left as it was customary for Facebook. All good and fine but for the fact that the second controller shows the toolbar and the other one does not and I found the navigation bar always drops from the top, differently of the standard push transition following the controller, thus producing a very unpleasant effect.
My problem is that the second view controller has no navigation bar until pushed and at that time it too late to produce a temporary one. 
This is the code of my attempt in the custom segue (the transition is particularly slow to understand what happens):

```
-(void) perform{
UIViewController* src=(UIViewController*)self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController* dest=(UIViewController*)self.destinationViewController;
CGRect originalSourceRect=src.view.frame;
float width=originalSourceRect.size.width;
CGRect f=CGRectMake(-width, originalSourceRect.origin.y, originalSourceRect.size.width, originalSourceRect.size.height);
CGRect destMain=CGRectMake(width, originalSourceRect.origin.y, originalSourceRect.size.width, originalSourceRect.size.height);
CGRect navigationBarFrame=src.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
CGRect nb=CGRectMake(-width, navigationBarFrame.origin.y, navigationBarFrame.size.width, navigationBarFrame.size.height);
dest.view.frame=f;
dest.navigationController.navigationBar.frame=nb;
[[src.view superview] addSubview:dest.view];
[dest.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    dest.view.frame=originalSourceRect;
    src.view.frame=destMain;
    dest.navigationController.navigationBar.frame=navigationBarFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [dest.view removeFromSuperview];
        [src.navigationController pushViewController:dest animated:NO];
    }];
}
```